# Which way does the air flow through my furnace?

Tags: hvac, furnace

Below is my furnace and I need to change the filter however I am unsure which way is the airflow direction. Red or Blue?

[image]

Comment: Remember that the air needs to be filtered BEFORE it enters the air handler and furnace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your diagram, the correct direction is the red arrow.

For more information, here's a diagram that shows the airflow in a furnace:

[image]